Why are my laravel assets not using HTTPS with vitejs
I am working on a new laravel 11 app with vitejs and I try to deploy it using Docker. Everything works well locally (using Docker Desktop), the live deployment in itself is working but my assets (css and js) are called using HTTP and not HTTPS which causes a (blocked:mixed-content) error.
That part is handled by vitejs and should be automatic. I previously deployed laravel 8 projects using the same configuration and the assets are called with HTTPS. The only things that changed in my Docker config is that I use php 8.2 instead of 8.1... The vitejs configuration is the exact same.
I tried several changes but I can't make it work
My vite.config.js file:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/sass/style.scss',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
    // base: process.env.APP_URL || '/',
    // server: {
    //     https: true,
    // },
    build: {
        manifest: true,
        outDir: 'public/build',
        emptyOutDir: true,
        rollupOptions: {
            output: {
                assetFileNames: '[name]-[hash][extname]',
            },
        },
    },
});

I tried with and without base, server and build. Nothing changes.
My .env file:
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=production
APP_KEY=setbutnotshown
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_TIMEZONE=UTC
APP_URL=https://myapp.example.com

the rest has not been changed except the DB data which is correct. I can run the migrations.
My Dockerfile :
# Base image
FROM php:8.2-apache

# Set working directory in the container
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    g++ \
    curl \
    libzip-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    zip \
    unzip \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Configure GD extension
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    --with-freetype=/usr/include/ \
    --with-jpeg=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu \
    --with-webp=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath zip

# Configure Apache
RUN echo "ServerName laravel-app.local" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
ENV APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/html/public
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf
RUN a2enmod rewrite headers

# Install Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Install Node.js (latest LTS version)
RUN apt-get update && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | bash - \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs \
    && npm install -g npm

# Copy the application files and set permissions
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data . /var/www/html

# Install PHP dependencies
RUN composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader

# Install Node.js dependencies and build assets
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

# Set proper permissions for storage and bootstrap cache
# RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/storage /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/storage /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache /var/www/html/public

# Expose port 80
EXPOSE 80

# Start Apache in foreground
CMD ["apache2-foreground"]

my docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'

services:
  my-app:
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: my-app
    ports:
      - "9005:80"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
      - ./storage:/var/www/html/storage
      - ./bootstrap/cache:/var/www/html/bootstrap/cache
    env_file:
      - .env

I tried with and without the volumes but no changes there either.
I checked the apache config file and everything is correct. SSL, servername...

Shouldn't you also expose port 443 in your Dockerfile?

And do you rewrite http requests to https in your apache config?

I added EXPOSE 443 below the line for 80. I have this in my apache config:         RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L].

I'm guessing that didn't solve the problem? I also see a mapping local port -> docker port in your docker-compose.yml - "9005:80". You probably also need one for port 443. Why not keep it 80 and 443?

It did not... I initially just copied and pasted the config I had in my previous laravel 8 projects. We deploy several projects on the same VM on Google Cloud Platform so we decided to start at 9000 and increment. I added - "9006:443" no change...

I found the solution... I added one line with the ASSET_URL below the APP_URL in my .env file and now it works.
APP_URL=https://myapp.example.com
ASSET_URL=https://myapp.example.com

